# Replace first character of all lines in text file with python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I have a txt file like this:

```
2 0.306250 0.376667 0.085000 0.120000
3 0.416250 0.385833 0.090000 0.118333
4 0.354375 0.509167 0.091250 0.121667
2 0.198125 0.206667 0.091250 0.123333
```

I would like to replace the first charterers i.e 2 , 3, 4, 2 of each lines with 0, 1, 2, 0 respectively. To do this I wrote a python script:

```
with open('WIN_20210421_15_46_55_Pro.txt') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
for item in lines:
    strs = item.strip('\n')
    if strs[0] == 2:
        strs[0].replace(str(2), str(0))
    elif strs[0] == 3:
        strs[0].replace(str(3), str(1))
    else:
        strs[0].replace(str(4), str(1))
```

The script not give me the same input file as out put. How may I get desire output with the same filename? like:

```
0 0.306250 0.376667 0.085000 0.120000
1 0.416250 0.385833 0.090000 0.118333
2 0.354375 0.509167 0.091250 0.121667
0 0.198125 0.206667 0.091250 0.123333
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`replace()` does not work "in-place". It returns a new string so you would have to assign it back to `item` in your example (`line`) in mine.

```
lines_in = [
    "2 0.306250 0.376667 0.085000 0.120000\n",
    "3 0.416250 0.385833 0.090000 0.118333\n",
    "4 0.354375 0.509167 0.091250 0.121667\n",
    "2 0.198125 0.206667 0.091250 0.123333\n"
]

for line in lines_in:
    first_char = line[0]
    if first_char == "2":
        line = line.replace("2", "0", 1)
    elif first_char == "3":
        line = line.replace("3", "1", 1)
    elif first_char == "4":
        line = line.replace("4", "2", 1)

    print(line)
```